# Jupyter Github Code Review

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook

When doing a code review on jupyter notebooks in github, it shows only the html code that generates the notebook. Are there any extensions that would enable github to show the rendered jupyter notebook, along with the ability to comment on cells for code review?

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood Notebook files are [JSON documents](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/nbformat.html). All the markdown, code, outputs are present in this JSON document. Since git diff used by GitHub is meant for text files, it's hard to read Jupyter Notebook diffs on GitHub.

I built a GitHub app [ReviewNB](https://www.reviewnb.com/) specifically to review Jupyter Notebooks on GitHub. It integrates directly with your repositories on GitHub and provides visual diff and commenting support (see screenshot below).

There's also [nbdime](https://github.com/jupyter/nbdime) if you just want to access rendered diff locally.

[image]